# Repeating and putting in a word on a PHP variable

Tags: php, string

```
$xcatname = 'Business';
$repeatmaincitiescat = 'London, Paris, New York';

$repeatmaincitiescat = str_replace(',', ' ' . $xcatname . ',', $repeatmaincitiescat).(empty($repeatmaincitiessubcat)?'':"");
```

Above codes giving this result: **London Business, Paris Business, New York Business**

However, I want this type of output,

**Business in London, Business in Paris, Business in New York**

I tried a few changes but it turns out to be in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to what hakre proposed is to use regular expressions. It's as close as you can get to your code, what you want to achieve cannot be done with a simple replace.

So, you could do (to be as close as possible to what you did):

```
<?php
$xcatname = 'Business';
$repeatmaincitiescat = 'London, Paris, New York';

$pattern = '/([^,]+)((,\s*)*)/';

function replace_match($matches) {
    global $xcatname;
    return $xcatname . ' in ' . $matches[1] . $matches[2];
}

$processed = preg_replace_callback($pattern, "replace_match", $repeatmaincitiescat);
// or simpler:
// $processed = preg_replace($pattern, $xcatname . " in  $1$2", $repeatmaincitiescat);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What about a simple mapping?

```
$xcatname = 'Business in %s';
$repeatmaincitiescat = 'London, Paris, New York';
$separator = ', ';
$repeatmaincitiescat = implode(
    $separator,
    array_map(function($v) use ($xcatname) {
            return sprintf($xcatname, $v);
        },
        explode($separator, $repeatmaincitiescat))
);

echo $repeatmaincitiescat;
```

Output:

```
Business in London, Business in Paris, Business in New York
```

And here a PHP 5.2 variant:

```
$xcatname = 'Business in %s';
$repeatmaincitiescat = 'London, Paris, New York';

$new = new MaskRepeat($repeatmaincitiescat, ', ', $xcatname);
echo $new; # Business in London, Business in Paris, Business in New York

class MaskRepeat {
    private $str;
    public function __construct($string, $separator, $mask) {
        $array = explode($separator, $string);
        foreach($array as &$value) {
            $value = sprintf($mask, $value);
        }
        $this->str = implode($separator, $array);
    }
    public function __toString() {return $this->str;}
}
```

Comment: I tried it turns out to be in syntax error? syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in

Comment: @Mas: Okay, PHP 5.2 I assume you are using. Let me think a bit what's nicest then ... .

Comment: I'll appreciate if you can make it work by amending my codes above, you just need to change the order in which variables are being echoed.

Answer (score 0):

$xcatname = 'Business in';
$repeatmaincitiescat = 'London, Paris, New York';

$repeatmaincitiescat = "$xcatname ".str_replace(',',','.$xcatname.'', $repeatmaincitiescat).(empty($repeatmaincitiessubcat)?'':"");

```
echo $repeatmaincitiescat ;
```